# How to select suitable value type in map function in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working with a programme that its value are large. each value consist of id numbers(integers seprated by comma):

value1: 1,207,688,4401,5432,40000,872111100

value2: 65,876,992,10002,9843221

I stored the value as text, but it gets 1 byte for each character.if the number of digits in id becomes large, it occupies a lot of space. do i store the value as text type?
Which format is the best to store that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory efficiency is a real concern and you know that the length of these IDs is never going to exceed `Long.MAX_VALUE`, I'd suggest the `LongWritable`.

Conversely, if you know that they will tend to be long enough that the value in bytes per character would be more memory efficient than stored in number form, then `Text` is perfectly suitable.

In the majority of cases, it isn't worth worrying about too much considering that it will be written out to file anyway - it's usually only worth converting to a `long` if there will be some form of calculation performed using it, otherwise you might as well stick with `Text` to avoid the conversion overhead on top of the initial parse.

Comment: the file size is very important in my program, my IDs must be seprated by comma(,). so can i use longwritable?

Comment: I'd suggest `Text` unless you will need to perform something arithmetic on it as a `long`.